# How can I handle Russian text in Perl?

Tags: perl, utf-8

I'm new to doing anything with any language that isn't english. So far the only I've ever done with programming is take input in the basic english letters + numbers and output it. Now I have to manipulate some text in Russian (especially from the Russian wikipedia page) but I have no clue where to start. I google and google but all I get are results that talk about unicode, UTF-8 and other things but those don't make sense to me because I'm not sure what those are referring to. Wikipedia entries themselves appear to be written for people who already know this stuff.

Can anyone point me to a good starting place?

Comment: I included a Unicode primer at the end of [Learning Perl](https://www.learning-perl.com). Basically, know the encoding you are reading, read the data in that encoding, and that's it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you should first get an idea of what Unicode is. Joel Spolsky's article [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) might be a good starting point (for experienced people it's quite uninformative, though).

After that you should look into how Perl handles Unicode, like taking a look at the [Perl Unicode Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html).

Comment: Thanks. I think that article is what I was looking for :)

Comment: Note: Actually Joel's article is pretty awful from a technical perspective and simplfies many things that probably shouldn't be. I'm not claiming I could write a better one but I've been proven many times by now that half-knowledge actually hurts and you probably won't have much more after reading said article.

Answer (score 0):

Encodings require that both sides understand what they get or what the other side expects. As long as all those agree, you don't actually have to do that much. You question is quite broad, but if there's a more specific problem, we can provide better advice. (heh, this is over a decade old, but popped up in the feed because a new answer showed up).

I don't know how you are fetching your data, but let's say it's a web request. Most of it is handled for you. I have no idea what this Russian wikipedia page is about.

```
use v5.10;

use utf8; # specifies this file as UTF-8, since there is Cyrillic
use open qw(:std :utf8); # input and output are UTF-8

use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $url = 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Заглавная_страница';
my $tx = Mojo::UserAgent->new->get($url);

# Mojo knows how to decode things based on the response headers
# such as "content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
my $para = $tx->res->dom->at( 'div#main-tfa p' )->all_text;

say $para;
```

The output show up correctly for me because I output UTF-8 and my terminal expects UTF-8:

```
Солнечное затмение — астрономическое явление, при котором Луна полностью или частично покрывает Солнце на некоторое время при наблюдении с определённой части Земли. Солнечные затмения происходят только в новолуние, причём из-за наклона орбиты Луны к плоскости эклиптики они случаются только от 2 до 5 раз в год.
```

Answer (score -1):

There are few Cyrillic encodings:

```
Windows-1251
Macintosh
ISO 8859-5
OEM 855
OEM 866
KOI8-R
KOI8-U
```

You only need to change encoding in `cmd`:

```
>>> chcp 1251
Active code page: 1251
```

And then change encoding of a file that uses Cyrillic to `windows-1251` for example. Encoding can be changed through text editors.

Save your file content before changing encoding or it might be lost.

Comment: You change the encoding to the one that handles the data you have, which might need another code page in Windows: https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8